# Python - arrays of tkinter widgets changing with radiobutton clicks

Tags: python, arrays, user-interface, tkinter, radio-button

I'm working on a GUI in Python using tkinter. I'm reading a text file in and creating GUI elements dynamically based on the lines in the text file. I have an array for each of my element types, which include labels, radiobutton variables (StringVars), and colored circles (drawn with create_oval). My goal is that when the user changes a radiobutton from "not assigned" to "in" or "out", the colored circle on that line will change from yellow to green. Here's how the GUI looks after the text file has been read in:

Item 1:        (o) in    () out    ()  not assigned     (G)

Item 2:        ()  in    () out    (o) not assigned     (Y)

Currently, I have a trace on the radiobutton StringVars so that I can call a method whenever one of the buttons is changed. My problem is figuring out which radiobutton was changed so that I can change the color of the circle on that line...

I'm currently going the route of duplicating the whole radiobutton StringVar array into a temp global array. When the trace function is called, I compare the temp array with what's currently in the array to figure out where the change is. I duplicate the array with: temp_radiobutton_vars = list(radiobutton_vars), but I'm not sure if this is the right route. My temp list and the current list always show the same results when I get() the StringVar, even after I changed the button. Any ideas on how to fix this, or maybe there's a better method to do what I'm looking to do...

Sorry for the long and not great explanation. If anyone needs more info or snippets of code, let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem. Since you are already using variable traces, perhaps the simplest solution is to pass the index of the canvas item to the callback.  You can use `lambda` or `functools.partial` for this task. You could also not use variable traces, but instead, associate a command with each radiobutton. In both cases you simply need to tell the callback which index to operate on.

In the following example, the callback takes a reference to a variable and the index to the canvas item. It fetches the value, looks up the color in a table, and then configures the canvas item:

```
def on_radiobutton(var, index):
    value = var.get()
    color = {"in": "green", "out": "red", "unassigned": "yellow"}
    self.canvas.itemconfigure(index, fill=color[value])
```

This is how the trace is set up using lambda (note that `name1`, `name2` and `op` are automatically sent by tkinter for every trace):

```
var = tk.StringVar()
rb0 = tk.Radiobutton(..., variable=var, value="in", text="in")
rb1 = tk.Radiobutton(..., variable=var, value="out", text="out")
rb2 = tk.Radiobutton(..., variable=var, value="unassigned", text="not assigned")

var.trace("w", lambda name1, name2, op, index=i, var=var:
          on_radiobutton(var, index))
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have the wrong idea with `Radiobuttons`. All "connected" `Radiobuttons` should have the same `variable` value; in this way, you can call `theVariable.get()` and compare that with the `value` of each `Radiobutton`; you shouldn't need a reference to every `Radiobutton`; nor should you have a `StringVar` for each `Radiobutton`, only each line.

**Edit**: I've expanded my example to show how this would work for more than one line. All that changed is now I check which line I have passed in my callback, and using that I know which line to update (in your case, which canvas to color). It's just some 2D list processing to check which `Radiobutton` is selected based upon which line is issuing the callback.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x200+500+400")
lines = [StringVar(), StringVar()]
strings = [["Hello", "Stack", "Overflow"], ["Whats", "Going", "On"]]
buttons = [[],[]]

l1 = Label(root, text = "Selection: ", justify = LEFT)
l1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = NW, padx = (0, 250))
l1.grid_propagate(False)

l2 = Label(root, text = "Selection: ", justify = LEFT)
l2.grid(column = 0, row = 4, sticky = NW, padx = (0, 250))
l2.grid_propagate(False)

def process(line):
    global l1, l2, strings, lines

    if line == lines[0]:
        # Since lines[0] was passed in to the callback, we know to update line 0; 
        # take that line's label (or canvas in your case)
        updateLine = 0
        updateLabel = l1
    else:
        # Otherwise take the other line
        updateLine = 1
        updateLabel = l2

    # These operations are performed within if/elif/else to show how you coul
    # choose a different process for each Radiobutton: example, coloring a canvas differently
    if lines[updateLine].get() == strings[updateLine][0]:
        # This means the first button of whatever line was selected
        updateLabel.config(text = "Selection: %s" %strings[updateLine][0])
    elif lines[updateLine].get() == strings[updateLine][1]:
        # This means the second button of whatever line was selected
        updateLabel.config(text = "Selection: %s" %strings[updateLine][1])
    else:
        # You get the idea
        updateLabel.config(text = "Selection: Bet you thought I'd say %s" %strings[updateLine][2])

# Must have a seperate row number because with multiple lines, we can't simply use 'i' or 'j'
rowNum = 1
for i in range(len(lines)):
    for j in range(len(strings[i])):
        buttons[i].append(Radiobutton(root, text = strings[i][j], variable = lines[i], value = strings[i][j], command = lambda line = lines[i]: process(line)))
        buttons[i][j].grid(column = 0, row = rowNum, sticky = NW)
        rowNum +=1
    rowNum += 2

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Great example, thanks for the help! Nice to have a full program I could run to see how everything works.